# How to correctly define and inject two different Spring Batch Job beans into the class that will run these jobs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am studying Spring Batch over Spring Boot following this tutorial:
https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-batch-tutorial-reading-information-from-a-rest-api/

Here the related GitHub project: https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-batch-examples/tree/master/reading-data/rest-api

I am finding some difficulties trying to understand what is the exact execution flow and how can I modify it in order to implement my custom behavior. I try to explain my doubts here:

This project contains the **SpringBatchExampleJobConfig** configuration class where are define the beans used by the Spring bean factory. These beans should be injected into the other classes (is it correct?):

```
@Configuration
public class SpringBatchExampleJobConfig {

    private static final String PROPERTY_REST_API_URL = "rest.api.url";

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<StudentDTO> itemReader(Environment environment, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        return new RESTStudentReader(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_REST_API_URL), restTemplate);
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<StudentDTO> itemWriter() {
        return new LoggingItemWriter();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a bean that represents the only step of our batch job.
     * @param reader
     * @param writer
     * @param stepBuilderFactory
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public Step exampleJobStep(ItemReader<StudentDTO> reader,
                               ItemWriter<StudentDTO> writer,
                               StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("exampleJobStep")
                .<StudentDTO, StudentDTO>chunk(1)
                .reader(reader)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a bean that represents our example batch job.
     * @param exampleJobStep
     * @param jobBuilderFactory
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public Job exampleJob(Step exampleJobStep,
                          JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("exampleJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(exampleJobStep)
                .end()
                .build();
    }
}
```

Basically it is defining the **itemReader** bean (that read data from a source), the **itemWriter** bean (that write data into a destination).

Then it is creating the **exampleJobStep** bean that define the step of this job: basically the step are: read from the source and pass the data to the writer that will write on the destination. Correct?

Finnally it is creating the **exampleJob** bean, this one:

```
@Bean
public Job exampleJob(Step exampleJobStep,
                      JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("exampleJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(exampleJobStep)
            .end()
            .build();
}
```

It should simply execute the steps defined by the **exampleJobStep** bean.

Is it my understanding correct untill now?

My doubt is: where and how is defined the job start (I mean the job represented by the previous **exampleJob** bean).

Into the GitHube code you can find the **SpringBatchExampleJobLauncher** that is where I think that the job is executed. Basically it is autowiring the Job object into the constructor:

```
@Autowired
public SpringBatchExampleJobLauncher(Job job, JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
    this.job = job;
    this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
}
```

My doubt is: it is autowiring by type? So it means that defining a bean like this in the beans configuration class:

```
@Bean
public Job exampleJob(Step exampleJobStep,
                      JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("exampleJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(exampleJobStep)
            .end()
            .build();
}
```

this is the bean that will be autowired into the constructor of the previous **SpringBatchExampleJobLauncher** class where my job is started?

If I have well understood how it works. Suppose now that I need to implement two different jobs and that I want to start both, what can I do to implement this behavior?

At the moment my **SpringBatchExampleJobLauncher** class contains

```
@Autowired
public SpringBatchExampleJobLauncher(Job job, JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
    this.job = job;
    this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
}

@Scheduled(cron = "0/10 * * * * *")
public void runSpringBatchExampleJob() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
    LOGGER.info("Spring Batch example job was started");

    jobLauncher.run(job, newExecution());

    LOGGER.info("Spring Batch example job was stopped");
}
```

it autowire (I suspect by type) my one and only **Job** object, than this job is started by the **runSpringBatchExampleJob** method.

Ok...my idea to have multiple job is to define two different bean into my **UpdateInfoBatchConfig** class. But in case what can I do to define two different bean having **Job** type? and how to correctly inject these two different job beans into my **SpringBatchExampleJobLauncher** class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way to solve the problem. The most convenient is to use Spring Boot. You can then add any number of job beans to the application context and Spring Boot will launch all of them on application start-up or only a subset if you use the parameter `spring.batch.job.names`. Please have a look the official documentation whether it fits your needs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.3/reference/html/howto.html#howto.batch

The most straightforward way to go about it, is to use bean names as qualifiers. By default, beans carry the name of the method producing them but you can also set it explicitly. For example, the following code sketch produces two job beans named `jobOne` and `jobTwo`

```
@Bean
Job jobOne() {
  return jobBuilderFactory
    ...
    .build();
}

@Bean("jobTwo") {
Job aMethodNameWithoutInfluenceOnTheBeanName() {
  return jobBuilderFactory
    ...
    .build();
}
```

You can then use the bean names to qualify which job bean you want to have auto-wired:

```
@Autowired
public SpringBatchExampleJobLauncher(
  @Qualifier("jobOne") Job job1,
  @Qualifier("jobTwo") Job job2,
  JobLauncher jobLauncher
) {
  this.job1 = job1;
  this.job2 = job2;
  this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
}
```

The same trick allows you to select which steps should be auto-wired into which job bean method.